How do I adjust the spacing between columns and rows in a TWebGridPanel component?
Is there a way to adjust the spacing between rows and columns in a TWebGridPanel component in TMS WEB Core?
If there is a way, then how?

Method 1:
The TWebGridPanel component has a GridLineWidth property that can be used to change the spacing between columns and rows. There's also a GridLineColor property to change the background color of the spacing area.

Method 2:
As an added alternative way if you'd like to adjust the spacing individually for columns or rows. All rows (TGridPanelRow) have MarginBottom and MarginTop properties. And all columns (TGridPanelColumn) have MarginLeft and MarginRight properties. These margin properties can be used to adjust the spacing also.

Bug in TMS WEB Core:
Also note that as of the current latest version (2.5.2.0) of TMS WEB Core, there is a bug. Even if you set all GridLineColor and margin properties to 0, there will still be a 2px gap between each item.
To remove this 2px gap, you'll need to write some CSS. The issue is that all <td> elements in the output HTML for the component contain padding: 1px CSS on it on some browsers. So to fix this, you need to simply set the padding to 0:
td {
  padding: 0;
}


I highly doubt it's "the ouput HTML" but instead the DOM you've inspected. It's a difference between pressing Ctrl+U to see the source and checking what the browser rendered out of that. As you formulated it, the markup would be increased by dozens of <td style="padding: 1px" which would be highly unprofessional by TMS.
